# How can I get Eclipselink working in a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, eclipselink, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

copied [my boot log](https://gist.github.com/xenoterracide/bc777b24ad7475c616dc) to a gist because it's too long for SE.

here's what I suspect is the important part of the message.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:641)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1157)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:280)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
... 145 more
```

also here's my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.xenoterracide</groupId>
<artifactId>rpf</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <start-class>com.xenoterracide.rpf.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>eclipselink-staticweave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>au.com.alderaan</groupId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>weave</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <logLevel>ALL</logLevel>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I'm using IDEA with it's built in "make" to compile and start the app.

I tried adding this class, but it didn't appear to help

```
class EntityManagerFactoryProducer {

@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
public EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory() {
  return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my-presistence-unit");
}

public void close(@Disposes EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
  entityManagerFactory.close();
}

@Produces
@RequestScoped
public EntityManager createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
  return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}

public void close(@Disposes EntityManager entityManager) {
  entityManager.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this sample project: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-sample-data-eclipselink ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where I received the same No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined exception.  My fix was to define the bean in my configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfiguration extends JpaBaseConfiguration {
...
    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my-persistence-unit");
    }
}
```